# how to do a count of results of a mysql query with group_concat and left joins

Tags: mysql, count, inner-join, group-concat

I am working on a webpage with pagination and one of the problems I am facing now, is that it doesn't work on my filter I created.

The main pagination is working by doing a count on my table by selecting everything with a certain user id. That works great without the filter, but with filter i need to change this query to add inner joins and group concat due to the stuff being filtered that is in other tables and connected to the main table by ID.

i now have this query for the filter:

```
SELECT DISTINCT games.gameID,games.idUsers,games.gamename,games.comments,games.dateofpurchase,games.lentoutto,games.gameinfo,games.price,games.pictureurl,games.finished,games.rating,games.releasedate, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT labels.labelname ORDER BY labels.labelname) AS labelname, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category.categoryname ORDER BY category.categoryname) AS categoryname, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gamemode.gamemode ORDER BY gamemode.gamemode) AS gamemode, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT platform.platform ORDER BY platform.platform) AS platform FROM games LEFT JOIN gamelabels ON gamelabels.gameID=games.gameID LEFT JOIN labels ON labels.labelID=gamelabels.labelID LEFT JOIN categoryconnect ON categoryconnect.gameID=games.gameID LEFT JOIN category ON category.categoryID=categoryconnect.gamescategory LEFT JOIN gamemodesconnect ON gamemodesconnect.gameID=games.gameID LEFT JOIN gamemode ON gamemode.gamemodeID=gamemodesconnect.gamemodeID LEFT JOIN platformconnect ON platformconnect.gameID=games.gameID LEFT JOIN platform ON platform.platformID=platformconnect.platformconnectID WHERE idUsers = '".$userId."' $filter GROUP BY games.gameID ORDER BY gamename
```

This filter query is working like a charm, but how can you do a count on the amount or rows this returns?

what I tried so far all gave me errors on the select part. Things like this:

```
SELECT COUNT ( DISTINCT games.gameID,games.idUsers,games.gamename,games.comments,games.dateofpurchase,games.lentoutto,games.gameinfo,games.price,games.pictureurl,games.finished,games.rating,games.releasedate, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT labels.labelname ORDER BY labels.labelname) AS labelname, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category.categoryname ORDER BY category.categoryname) AS categoryname, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gamemode.gamemode ORDER BY gamemode.gamemode) AS gamemode, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT platform.platform ORDER BY platform.platform) AS platform) FROM games LEFT JOIN gamelabels ON gamelabels.gameID=games.gameID LEFT JOIN labels ON labels.labelID=gamelabels.labelID LEFT JOIN categoryconnect ON categoryconnect.gameID=games.gameID LEFT JOIN category ON category.categoryID=categoryconnect.gamescategory LEFT JOIN gamemodesconnect ON gamemodesconnect.gameID=games.gameID LEFT JOIN gamemode ON gamemode.gamemodeID=gamemodesconnect.gamemodeID LEFT JOIN platformconnect ON platformconnect.gameID=games.gameID LEFT JOIN platform ON platform.platformID=platformconnect.platformconnectID WHERE idUsers = '".$userId."' $filter GROUP BY games.gameID ORDER BY gamename
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is the right approach, using a subquery. In MySQL, each subquery table needs an identifier, which is passed after the closing parenthesis which wraps the query, like so:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT games.gameID,games.idUsers,games.gamename,games.comments,games.dateofpurchase,games.lentoutto,games.gameinfo,games.price,games.pictureurl,games.finished,games.rating,games.releasedate, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT labels.labelname ORDER BY labels.labelname) AS labelname, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT category.categoryname ORDER BY category.categoryname) AS categoryname, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT gamemode.gamemode ORDER BY gamemode.gamemode) AS gamemode, GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT platform.platform ORDER BY platform.platform) AS platform FROM games LEFT JOIN gamelabels ON gamelabels.gameID=games.gameID LEFT JOIN labels ON labels.labelID=gamelabels.labelID LEFT JOIN categoryconnect ON categoryconnect.gameID=games.gameID LEFT JOIN category ON category.categoryID=categoryconnect.gamescategory LEFT JOIN gamemodesconnect ON gamemodesconnect.gameID=games.gameID LEFT JOIN gamemode ON gamemode.gamemodeID=gamemodesconnect.gamemodeID LEFT JOIN platformconnect ON platformconnect.gameID=games.gameID LEFT JOIN platform ON platform.platformID=platformconnect.platformconnectID WHERE idUsers = '".$userId."' $filter GROUP BY games.gameID ORDER BY gamename
) count_test;
```

Comment: Thx Tyreal! That does seem to work! But for my understandings (this whole project is a big learning curve for me on php and mysql), what you do, is make a temp column for the count (count_test) and put the whole original query as a from where you normally would put the columns you select from?

Comment: Welcome. What we have done is creating a temporary table with just one column (the count(*)). The way we created the temporary table is called a subquery. We could have added more columns to the subquery as well, it behaves very much like a regular table. What I can recommend is using the `EXPLAIN` function of MySQL. For each SELECT query, you can prepend EXPLAIN, and MySQL's analyzer will return useful information about how it processes the query and how it is structured. It will also report subqueries, if there are any.

Comment: Thanks for this explanation 